# Часть selenium тестов игнорируется при запуске в Jenkins (запускается 2 из 4)

Tags: selenium, maven, jenkins

Все тесты локально работают, но при запуске в Jenkins часть из них игнорируется. Все тесты лежат в одной папке src/test/java/ru/mytests
Тесты которые не запускаются скопированы  по сути с тех, которые работают. В чём может быть причина?

В pom.xml следующие данные:

````
  <plugins>
      <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.19.1</version>
      </plugin>
  </plugins>
   </build>

  <dependencies>
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
      <dependency>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          <version>4.13</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>

      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
          <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
          <version>3.141.59</version>
      </dependency>```
````

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в названии тестов
По умолчанию запускаются только классы с такими названиями: Test*, *Test, *TestCase;
Плюс все они должны быть классами, а у меня лежали вперемешку классы и Java файлы